# How to generate PDF of a HTML table in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular

I want to generate PDF of a html table in an Angular 8 project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629163/angular-7-convert-html-to-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7: convert HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629163/angular-7-convert-html-to-pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your ts file.**

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';


exportAsPDF()
{
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.autoTable({html: '#table'});
  doc.save(this.templateName+".pdf");
}
```

**I hope this will help.**